# How do I create a performant scope based on the virtual attributes of an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `Node` model. Each `node` object has a virtual attribute called `user_tags` or `user_tag_list` which was inherited from `acts_as_taggable`.

It looks like this:

```
[24] pry(main)> n
=> #<Node id: 85, name: "House Fire 2", family_tree_id: 57, user_id: 57, media_id: 228, media_type: "Video", created_at: "2015-05-15 00:20:26", updated_at: "2015-05-20 01:06:34", circa: nil, is_comment: nil, cached_votes_total: 0, cached_votes_score: 0, cached_votes_up: 0, cached_votes_down: 0, cached_weighted_score: 0, cached_weighted_total: 0, cached_weighted_average: 0.0>
[25] pry(main)> n.user_tags
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."context" = 'user_tags'  [["taggable_id", 85], ["taggable_type", "Node"]]
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 4, name: "gerry@test.com", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 6, name: "danny@test.com", taggings_count: 1>]
[26] pry(main)> n.user_tag_list
=> ["gerry@test.com", "danny@test.com"]
```

What I would like to do is create a scope that returns all user records that have been tagged on a node. i.e. where their email would appear in the list of some `n.user_tags` or `n.user_tag_list`.

I have tried this:

```
  scope :with_tagged_users, -> (node) { node.user_tag_list.collect do |tag|
                              User.find_by email: tag
                            end
                          }
```

The issue with this is that this is just for 1 `node` object. i.e. I would have to do `Node.tagged_users(node)` which kinda defeats the purpose of having a scope on the entire model.

I could also do an iteration through all the nodes and check to see if `user_tags.empty?` on each, but that doesn't seem performant.

I feel like there should be a way to do this with either `joins` or `includes` or some other built-in method that should be able to do this simply & fast, but I can't quite come up with it.

So, to be clear, ideally I would like to do `Node.with_tagged_users` and that should return a list of all the users that are tagged on any node, preferably with no duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know the exact tables of acts_as_taggable but i think they are named: "taggings" and "tags"

knowing this you could do:

- fetch all tags

  ```
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where("id in (?)", ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(taggable_type: 'Node').pluck(:tag_id))
  ```
- fetch nodes that have tags

  ```
  Node.where("id in (?)", ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(taggable_type: 'Node').pluck(:taggable_id))
  ```
- in a class method you can do

  ```
  def self.with_tagged_users
    Node.where("id in (?)", ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(taggable_type: 'Node').pluck(:taggable_id))
  end
  ```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I achieved it a different way, i.e. using a `cache_column` of the tags. So it isn't an exact answer for what I was trying to do, but it got the same result. But this is what I was looking for. I would likely write a scope that looks similar to your 2nd option here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make this just an instance method rather than a scope, but here's the scope first:

```
scope :with_tagged_users, -> (node) { User.find_by email: node.user_tag_list }
```

And very similarly, here's the query as an instance method on `Node`:

```
def tagged_users
  User.find_by email: user_tag_list
end
```

Comment: Hrmm....this doesn't quite cover it though. As in, what I am trying to do is call `Node.with_tagged_users` and it gives me an AR collection of ALL the nodes that have a value in their respective `node.user_tag_list`. i.e. I don't want to call `tagged_users` on 1 specific node. i.e. Assume I have 10 `Nodes` in my DB. 5 of which have `user_tags`. I want to be able to do `Node.with_tagged_users` and it should return those 5. This answer doesn't. This answer requires me to pre-specify a single node that has `user_tags` and returns the list of users that have been tagged. i.e. it only does half.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [squeel gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) helpful.  I think its 'sifter' functionality might allow you to achieve your goal.  I will try to work up an example when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Cristi's approach above is simply adding a `cache_column` called `cached_num_user_tags`.

I then have to make sure to add logic to increment or decrement that as tags are added and removed.

But in my scope, I simply do something like this:

```
scope :with_tagged_users, -> { Node.where('cached_num_user_tags > 0') }
```

So, granted...it does the query on an actual attribute, not a virtual attribute like I initially asked....but it gave me a workable solution.